# INDEX/MATCH with 4 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with 2 sheets - one sheet contains my items, prices, codes, etc. and the other sheet is for cross-matching with competitors.

I've included an Excel file and image below.

I want to be able to generate my code automatically when manually entering any of my competitor's codes. I was able to do `INDEX/MATCH` but I was only able to match with one column (I'm assuming they're all in one sheet to make it easier). Here is my formula:

`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(K2,E:E,0)`

So this is looking only in `E:E`, when I tried to enter a different column such as `C:C` or `D:D` it returns an error.

I tried to do the `MATCH` as `C:G` but it gave an error right away.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why match gave you error is because it's looking for an array and you put in multiple columns.

There is definitely a more elegant way to do this but this is the first one that I came up with.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K2,C:C,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K2,D:D,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K2,E:E,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K2,F:F,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K2,G:G,0)),"")))))
```

Comment: thank you very very much for your help..  this really solved my problem and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

### Index/Match Combination

Please try this formula:

> {=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(1,(K2=$C$2:$C$5)+(K2=$D$2:$D$5)+(K2=$E$2:$E$5)+(K2=$F$2:$F$5)+(K2=$G$2:$G$5),0))}

Instruction: Paste the formula {without the curly brackets} to the formula bar and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while the cell is still active. This will create an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d). Hence, the curly brackets. Please take note though that manually entering the curly brackets will not work.

Description:

- *The INDEX function returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range.*[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- *The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range.*[2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Syntax:

The INDEX function has two forms—Array and Reference form. We're going use the Reference form in this case.

- *INDEX(reference, row_num, [column_num], [area_num])*[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- *MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])*[2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Explanation:

To simplify, we're going to use this form:

> INDEX(reference, MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]))

The `INDEX` function returns a value from the reference `My code` column (B1:B5) based on the `row_num` argument, which serves as an index number to point to the right cell, and we're going to do that by substituting `row_num` with `MATCH` function.

`MATCH` function, on the other hand, returns the relative position of a value in `competitor`*`n`* column that matches the value in individual cells of the `competitor code` column.

To make it work with multiple lookup range, we're going to create arrays of boolean values (TRUE/FALSE, aka logical values) by comparing values from individual cells in `competitor code` column with values in individual `competitor`*`n`* columns. Now, we convert these boolean values into numerical values by performing a mathematical operation that does not alter its implied value (i.e. TRUE=1, FALSE=0). We're going to add these values directly to make it simple. The resulting array have four index with two possible values: 1 or 0. Since each item in `MATCH`'s `lookup_array` is unique, then there can be only one `TRUE` or `1`. The rest are `FALSE` or `0`'s. So, with that knowledge, we're going to use it as our `lookup_value`.

Let's dissect the formula:

> =INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,(K2=C2:C5)+(K2=D2:D5)+(K2=E2:E5)+(K2=F2:F5)+(K2=G2:G5),0))

**`My code 2`** `=` `INDEX({"My code 1";"My code 2";"My code 3";"My code 4"},MATCH)`

**`My code 2`** `=` `INDEX({"My code 1";"My code 2";"My code 3";"My code 4"},(2))`

**`2`** `=` `MATCH(1,(K2=C2:C5)+(K2=D2:D5)+(K2=E2:E5)+(K2=F2:F5)+(K2=G2:G5),0)`

```
2 =MATCH(1,
    {FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}+
    {FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}+
    {FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}+
    {FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}+
    {FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE},0))
```

OR

```
=MATCH(1,
    {0;0;0;0}+
    {0;0;0;0}+
    {0;0;0;0}+
    {0;0;0;0}+
    {0;1;0;0},0))
    =========
    {0;1;0;0},0))
```

**`2`** `=` `MATCH(1,{0;1;0;0},0))`

I hope this answer is helpful.

References and links:

1. [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
2. [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
3. [Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)

Comment: thank you very very much for your help..  i do appreciate